# Adding Primefaces references in Maven Project?

Tags: java, maven, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have been finding difficulties in adding primefaces references to my web application project. I have added all the required references that are required in order to run primefaces in my project. But i dont know which reference is still pending. Request you all to please guide.

Below is my POM.xml contents

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>myprojectweb</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myproject Web Project</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../myproject</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>           

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.16.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
            <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.16.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.16.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-wlp-managed-8.5</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Beta1</version>
        </dependency>                                           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>                       
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myprojectcommon</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myprojectejb</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <!-- <compilerArguments>
                           <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${war-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/web.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin-version>2.5.1</compiler-plugin-version>
        <war-plugin-version>2.4</war-plugin-version>
    </properties>
</project>t>
```

And i find the below error when i run my application:

```
[27/10/14 15:02:51:841 IST] 00000131 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Faces Servlet]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.primefaces.event.NodeSelectEvent
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodsImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:748)
            at java.beans.StandardBeanInfo.introspectMethods(StandardBeanInfo.java:665)
            at java.beans.StandardBeanInfo.introspectMethods(StandardBeanInfo.java:652)
            at java.beans.StandardBeanInfo.<init>(StandardBeanInfo.java:153)
            at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfoImpl(Introspector.java:272)
            at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfoImplAndInit(Introspector.java:389)
            at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:171)
            at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.<init>(BeanELResolver.java:218)
            at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:315)
            at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:89)
            at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:55)
            at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
            at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:174)
            at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:283)
            at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.toString(ELText.java:202)
            at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction.write(AttributeInstruction.java:51)
            at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:46)
            at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:214)
            at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:622)
            at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:622)
            at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:622)
            at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:622)
            at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1320)
            at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
            at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
            at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:240)
            at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
            at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
            at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.event.NodeSelectEvent
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
            at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:688)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:667)
            at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:119)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
```

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems you have to add the exception stack trace (available in your console, not in browser) to make it possible for anyone to inspect the exact cause of your problem.

Comment: Looking at your WAR plugin configuration, it seems like you're setting it up to exclude all jar files in WEB-INF/lib ... so then it wouldn't be much of a surprise that primefaces is spontaneously missing upon deployment. you probably put that configuration because the list of dependencies is really bad- there are many duplicates in there and many API dependencies (faces, servlet, JSP) which must never be deployed with the application.

Comment: @Gimby I just read [here](http://javing.blogspot.fr/2013/01/how-to-create-new-jsf-21-project-and.html) that, when deploying on JBoss, the faces and servlet dependencies are needed. How can that be?

Comment: Because that blog is very wrong? Just because it is on the internet doesn't make it true. The information in that blog is about as poor as you can make it.

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam : I have added the exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your stack trace shows, the `org.primefaces.event.NodeSelectEvent` class doesn't exist in your runtime class path and if you take a look at your pom.xml (As mentioned by @Gimby in comments), you explicitly asked maven not to include your library folder in your final packaged war file:

`<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>`

I think removing the above configuration from 'maven-war-plugin' will resolve your issue (or at least let you go to the next error ;)

Comment: +1 from my side...Solved my primefaces exception as well..:-)